# How to get a vertical scroll bar on Google Dashboard Category Selector

Tags: javascript, xml, google-visualization, google-sites

**My Problem**

I have a Google visualization dashboard in a [Google site](https://sites.google.com/site/letsrespondtoolkit/climate-change-resources/census-data). When the user selects the drop down menu (CategorySelector) the very first item is automatically selected and populated on the dashboard (in this example "//Khara Hais Local Municipality"). This only happens when there are multiple entries in the drop down menu which go past the bottom of the webpage. With a short list of items (e.g 5) I don't get the problem.

**The Code**

The dashboard is embedded in the site as an [`XML` gadget](https://sites.google.com/site/letsrespondtoolkit/South_Africa_Census_Dashboard.xml). Long story, but Google site won't let me embed the `HTML`directly, so it has to be wrapped in `XML`.

**Proposed Solution**

I think the best way to resolve this is to minimise the number of entries in the category selector with a vertical scroll bar, but I dont know how to code this in the Google visualization. Any help would be great

Comment: Thanks I have a solution. I added the following section after the </head>

Comment: <style type="text/css">
  .goog-menu-vertical {overflow-y:scroll; max-height:300px}
</style>